# I couldn't get the mega stone upgrade

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have completed the game, beaten my rival, and have talked to Professor Sycamore. but I didn't get the upgrade and I just finished the looker quest line. And I am not restarting the game. so how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have beaten your rival and talked to Sycamore in front of the sundial, you should be able to find Mega Stones between 8-9 PM. If this is inconvenient for you, you can always change your 3DS clock.

EDIT: I just thought of this, did you actually TOUCH the sundial when you were prompted to? The game might not let you leave before you do, but I have to make sure.